# Solr function query that operates on count of multivalued field

Tags: solr

Can I, within a Solr function query, count the number of values in a multivalued field? How would I write a function query that returns documents with, say, 3 or more values for a particular field?

Comment: just to help someone: myField:[* TO *] returns if has more than 0 values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here's the function query reference](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery), and it doesn't list anything like that, so I think it's safe to assume that there's no such thing.

If the value count is somehow relevant in your case, add it as a separate int field, then operate on that field.

Comment: Thanks. It was, as you guessed, pretty easy to just store the count in a separate field and operate on that.

Comment: @Dave did you store the count manually, or is there a way for the count field to refer to the multivalued field so that as soon as the multivalued field changes, the count updates itself ?

Comment: Take a look at [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html) as mentioned  here in another SO question [solr-count-multi-valued-fields-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769405/solr-count-multi-valued-fields-query)