# Query on multivalued fields size

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I need a help. I need a query that the results are based on a multivalued field size. For example: I want all documents with 5 skus. I have a multivalued field named skulist. Can i search for multivalued fields size? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can get the size of a multi valued field using SOLR query. If indexing documents again is not an issue , you can have another integer field which can keep track of the size of your multi valued field. You will have to increment it through your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot but indexing it again is an issue cause the core is mantaneid by another team. I Will treat in my codes. I would like to get only documents with fields'size that i need to avoid unmatched documents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr function query that operates on count of multivalued field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240092/solr-function-query-that-operates-on-count-of-multivalued-field)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240092/solr-function-query-that-operates-on-count-of-multivalued-field?rq=1