# SOLR count multi valued fields query

Tags: solr

Is it possible to create a solr query where only documents are returned which have more than one entries in a multi valued field. For example:

```
docs: [
  {
    id: 1,
    myfield: ["hello word", "hello stackoverflow"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    myfield: ["hello word"]
  }
]
```

And my naive sample query just for explanation what I want:

```
/select?q=count(myfield.length, 'eq', 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is but not "out of the box". A solution in order to achieve what you're looking for is to use [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html) along with a new field called in your case myfield_count. For instance:

```
docs: [
  {
    id: 1,
    myfield: ["hello word", "hello stackoverflow"]
    myfield_count: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    myfield: ["hello word"]
    myfield_count: 1
  }
]
```

After that you can simply use a boolean function in order to filter or score for myfield_count>1.

Comment: Thanks AR1, not quite the solution im looking for but i guess its the only way.