# How to count multi-valued Field in solr

Tags: solr

I Want to count multi-valued field in SOLR.

I have two multi-valued fields store_id and filter_id
and i want to count these field value like

store_id = {0,3,7} 
count_store_id = 3

filter_id = {12,13,20,22,59,61,62,145}
count_filter_id = 8

[image]

and is that possible when store_id is update then count_store_id also update in solr by default

@@ Ashraful Islam - As you told me i'll change it but there is nothing going happen here i attach image find it.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to count the size of store_id or filter_id ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240092/solr-function-query-that-operates-on-count-of-multivalued-field

Comment: I misunderstood the question  check the above link

Comment: no, i want no of count in these fields like. store_id={0,2,9}  so here count of store_id is 3 similar as filter_id

Comment: You can't do this in solr with query. You have to create a field in solr and store the count when creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as suggested by Alexandre Rafalovitch, by using defining custom `UpdaterequestProcessor` you can get the count value of multivalued field.

add below lines in your solrconfig.xml

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="multivaluecountnum" default="true">
   <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="source">store_id</str>
     <str name="dest">store_id_count</str>
   </processor>
<processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="source">filter_id</str>
     <str name="dest">filter_id_count</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="fieldName">store_id_count</str>
   </processor>
 <processor class="solr.CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="fieldName">filter_id_count</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="fieldName">store_id_count</str>
     <int name="value">0</int>
   </processor>
<processor class="solr.DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="fieldName">filter_id_count</str>
     <int name="value">0</int>
   </processor>
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Do not forget to add RunUpdateProcessorFactory at the end of any chains you define in solrconfig.xml

Add store_id_count and filter_id_count fields in schema file

```
   <field name="store_id_count" type="int" stored="true"/>
   <field name="filter_id_count" type="int" stored="true"/>
```

Reindex docs and query, you will see two new fields store_id_count and filter_id_count in result.

Hope this Helps,
Vinod.

Comment: Thanks Vinod, Now its working when i import data from mysql database.

Comment: but there is one issue when i insert new document then it will not working. it is working only when i import data from data not when i insert a new document in data base.

Comment: this process happens at solr side. for every doc during indexing into solr, one new field (count, in your case)is computed and added to doc. then updated doc with new field is indexed into Solr.

Comment: Wow, very helpful answer, but I have one question: How can perform similar behavior with partial update of cloned multivalued field? I am performing an update of multivalued field (adding one new value to it) and it seems that in this case counter is set to 1 instead of old-counter-value +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom [UpdateRequestProcessor chain](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors) that uses [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html).